# How to change the anchorPoint for a transformation in UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, catransform3d, anchorpoint

I am using `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` to apply a transform to one of my cells.

The transform I would like to apply is

```
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(dx, dy, 0);
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DScale(transform, rx, ry, 1);
```

with numbers `dx`, `dy`, `rx` and `ry`.

The problem is that this expression is ok for an `anchorPoint` which is not the center of my cell. It seems that the default `anchorPoint` is the middle. So, I would like to specify to my `attributes` what is the `anchorPoint`.

**Is there a way to do that?**

---

PS: I don't have much control for transforming my cell other than the attributes. Actually, this transform is applied in the method `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath`